# Wordpress Rest API - invalid nonce with Backbone Client

Tags: javascript, wordpress, backbone.js, wordpress-rest-api, nonce

I'm using the built-in Backbone Client whenever I try to make a request it gives me this error: `{"code":"rest_cookie_invalid_nonce","message":"Cookie nonce is invalid","data":{"status":403}}`

I read the Rest [API Handbook - Authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/), and from what I've learned I don't need to do any manual setting.

Plugins in use:

- Askimet Anti-spam
- WP Fastest Cache
- iThemes
- WP Bannerize
- Yoast

I'm using the client for for lazyloading and search, only `GET` requests of Posts collections.

Answer (score 0):

I delete `wpApiSettings.nonce` at the top of my app.js, perhaps not an ideal solution but it works.